# Using Fermat's Little Theorem to Show Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

I was asked to prove, using Fermat's Little Theorem, that $11|5^{10n+8}-4$ for $n\ge0$. I proved it but I was wondering whether there's an easier way (still using Fermat's). Here is my proof:

\begin{alignat}{3}
11|5^{10n+8}-4&\iff5^{10n+8}-4&&\equiv0 &&&\mod11\\
\quad&\iff 25^{5n+4}-4&&\equiv0 &&&\mod 11\\
\quad&\iff \qquad3^{5n+4}&&\equiv 4 &&&\mod 11\\
\quad&\iff \qquad3^{5n+5}&&\equiv 12 &&&\mod 11\\
\quad&\iff \qquad3^{5(n+1)}&&\equiv 1 &&&\mod 11.\\
\end{alignat}
For $n\ge1$, let S(n) be the statement

$$ S(n) :3^{5(n+1)}\equiv 1 \mod 11.$$  We will prove by induction on $n$ that $S(n)$ holds.

**Base case ($n=1$)**. By Fermat's Little Theorem, $S(1)$ is true.

**Inductive Step**. Fix some $k\ge1$ and suppose $S(k)$ is true. To be shown is that the statement
$$S(k+1):3^{5(k+2)}\equiv 1 \mod 11$$ follows. Beginning with the LHS of $S(k+1)$,

\begin{alignat}2
\quad&3^{5(k+2)}&&=3^{5(k+1)+5}\tag{1}\\
\quad&\ \implies &&=3^{5}3^{5(k+1)}\tag{2}\\
\quad& \overset{\text{IH}}{\implies} &&\equiv3^{5}(1)\mod 11\tag{3}\\
\quad&\ \implies &&\equiv1\mod 11\tag{4},\\
\end{alignat}
arriving to the RHS of $S(k+1)$, concluding the inductive step. It is proved, then, by MI that $S(n)$ holds for all $n\ge1.$ Since $S(0)$ holds by $(4)$, then $S(n)$ is true for all $n\ge0$.

Comment: This is far too complicated. Note that $5^8\equiv4\mod{11}$, and that by Fermat's Little Theorem, $5^{10}\equiv1\mod{11}$. The rest follows.

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$
5^{10n+8} = 5^{10n} 5^8 =  (5^{10})^n 5^8 \equiv 1 \cdot 5^8 \equiv 4 \bmod 11
$$

Comment: From a comment by Don Thousand.

Comment: In particular, repeated squaring gives $5^2=3,\,5^4=-2,\,5^8=4$.

Answer (score 4):

- multiply by 25 getting $5^{10(n+1)}-100$
- Take remainders using Fermat, getting $1-1\equiv 0\pmod{11}$

Comment: +1 That's one way I'd show it too. Worth emphasis is that $\bmod 11\!\!:\,\ 25 x\equiv 0 \iff x\equiv 0\ $ by $\ 25\,$ is invertible (so cancellable).

Comment: It's not mod for that first part simply $p|a\implies p|ab$ ...

Comment: Of course we can rewrite congruences in divisibility language, but generally that's not a good thing to do since it often obfuscates innate *arithmetical* structure.

Comment: I didn't really use much ...

Comment: To finish requires your way you could justify the inference $\ 11\mid 25x \,\Rightarrow\, 11\mid x,\,$ which is the divisibility form of what I wrote above. We can't possibly know what you intended to "use much" since you did not finish the argument, i.e. you omitted that step.

Comment: I honestly don't care bill. I'm not here to teach advanced versions of crap all.

Comment: It has little to do with "advanced". Proofs need to be rigorous and complete at *all*  levels. The point of my initial comment was to remind readers that this argument  depends on that inference. Failing to recognize that will quickly lead one astray when working mod composites, e.g. $\bmod 10\!:\ 2x\equiv 0\not\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 0,\,$ e.g. $\,x = 5\ \ $

Comment: It would only be advanced in my country as of the time I graduated, we had barely learned sequences of difference.

Answer (score 3):

Much easier way!

By FLT $5^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ so $5^{10n+8}\equiv 5^8$ and  $5^{10n +8} -4  \equiv 5^8 -4\pmod {11}$.

So you just have to show that *one* case the $5^8 \equiv 4   \pmod {11}$.  Then *every* case will be $5^{10n + 8} - 4\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$

Admittedly that requirse calculations but there are 3 ways, each more clever than the other

1) $5^2 = 25\equiv 3 \pmod {11}$.  $5^4\equiv 3^2 \equiv 9\equiv -2 \pmod {11}$. $5^8\equiv (-2)^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {11}$.

2) $5^8*5^2 \equiv 5^{10} \equiv 1\pmod {11}$

$5^8*5^2 \equiv 5^8*3 \equiv 1\pmod{11}$ so as $11$ is prime $3^{-1}$ exist as is.... $1 \equiv 12=3*4\pmod{11}$ so $5^8*3*4 \equiv 4\pmod {11}$ and $5^8\equiv 4\pmod {11}$.

3) I'll admit I didn't come up with this.

If $5^8 -4 \equiv A\pmod{11}$ then

$(5^8-4)*25 \equiv A*25\pmod{11}$

$5^{10} - 100 \equiv 3A$

$1 - 1 \equiv 3A$

$3A \equiv 0\pmod {11}$ and as $11$ is primes $A\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$.

Comment: persistence of 0 Mod, modulo multiples for the win.

Answer (score 2):

$$10n+8=10(n+1)-2$$
we know that $5^{10}\equiv 1 \mod 11$ by Fermat.

we just need to prove that
$$5^{-2}-2^2=$$
$$(5^{-1}+2)(5^{-1}-2)\equiv 0 \mod 11$$

which is true since the inverse $5^{-1}$ is $9$ .

Answer (score 1):

$10\equiv-1\bmod11,$ so  $10^8 \equiv(-1)^8=1\bmod11,$

so $5^{10n+8}\equiv5^8\equiv5^82^{10}=10^82^2\equiv4\bmod 11,$

since $5^{10}$ and $2^{10}\equiv1\bmod11$ by Fermat's little theorem.